# Jenkins pipeline for parallel cross browser testing

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, selenoid

I need to find solution/s for next case. There is selenoid in docker which runs browsers in containers, the tests should be run in parallel for some browsers. I made pipeline in Jenkins for that goal. And all tests run in parallel for browsers but they work with the same workspace and I got errors from time to time. How can I make Jenkins settings or pipeline configuration to have each browser branch with its own workspace or thomething else to avoid conflicts.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'MAVEN_HOME'
    }
    stages {
        stage('setup parameters') {
            steps {
                script {
                    properties([
                        parameters([
                        choice(
                            choices: ['chrome', 'firefox', 'all'],
                            name: 'browser'
                        )
                    ])
                    ])
                }
            }
        }
        stage('clone code') {
            steps {
                echo 'git'
                git branch: 'feature/selenoid-integration', credentialsId: '......', url: 'https://github.com/.../selenide-web-test-project'
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (browser.equals("chrome")) {
                        echo 'chrome'
                        bat 'mvn clean -Dbrowser.type=chrome test'
                    }
                    if (browser.equals("firefox")) {
                        echo 'firefox'
                        bat 'mvn clean -Dbrowser.type=firefox test'
                    }
                    if (browser.equals("all")) {
                        echo 'all'
                        parallel(
                        chrome: {
                            bat 'mvn clean -Dbrowser.type=chrome test'
                        },
                        firefox: {
                            bat 'mvn clean -Dbrowser.type=firefox test'
                        }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using formatting to make this question - and the code example legible. You can also clean up the typos like "thomething".

Comment: I tried from mobile browser - but it looks like a bug. Formatting didn't work. I tried some times). From desktop everything is ok, I got success.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the code.  As @vania-pooh states in their answer, using docker makes the most sense for this. Using two MVN calls in parallel has many possible problems. One way is to create subdirectories in each branch (e.g. via XCOPY) that are copies of the main branch. But that doesn't solve the problem of running mvn in parallel which will use the same ~/.m2 cache for both operations.

For best isolation running on multiple agents is recommended if containers is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would be to use Selenium Grid. You can set up different nodes for each browser. (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/)

Comment: But selenoid is more modern way which was creted to avoid selenium grid.. It's what I know about selenoid and selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution that is using containers, including Selenoid and Selenium Grid will do the trick. This is because if you start browser sessions in containers, they don't have accumulated state: cache, cookies, temporary files. Because of that tests are more reliable than without containers.